# server for verifying users phone number on website form

Tags: php, html, web, sms, verification

in short: building a website form so the user can enter his information including his phone number, and i need a way to verify his phone number. Am using PHP. any simple code/widget that i could add to the page without any installation or SDKs?

been looking for a server who can help me add a widget/code to my live website so the user verifies his phone number before signing in up.

I have found a lot of servers, some can't understand their docs; they required installing SDKs, and I can't finger out how to do that on the host server! if that what it means!
others add other options with the SMS, like call or email and I don't want that.

the last one I found firebase way, but I also couldn't understand how!

OK, my question is: is there a server or a way that is only to send SMS with code and check the code? i mean even if just send SMS and i could add the code to it and verify it with the function I could write.

i think it is so easy to do, but been looking for couple days and i don't why i couldn't find what i need!

Comment: To verify the phone number you dont need a special server. You just need your normal webserver with a script that send either a SMS or voice message by calling the phone number. The SMS or vocie message needs to contain the code which the users then enters and will be checked simliar to a password. Otherwise you need to finde a commercial service (not server) that does it for you. Sending a SMS or phone call emssage costs money. I see no way how elese you want to actually verify the phone number. However, I miss there a specific coding issue that would make this question on topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to autheticate the user with a phone number you can take a look on firebase

here is the documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Also you can watch firebase tutorials series on youtube

Answer (score 0):

This question too specific and there is no exac answer.
Mostly SMS depends to local providers (for simple cases). If you get SMS plan your provider and if supporting REST API or SOAP you can use simply. This info should be in docs.

In the worst case scenario, if there is not any info you can check SDK source code and extract SMS parts then create your function or class. After all if, else, basic CRUD operations.

When you need all services (SMS, Call etc.) SDK best way doing this. Yes SDK may has a lot of dependencies and complex but you can trust.